# How to build a different Jenkins pipeline and pull the artifacts

Tags: jenkins

I have Job A & Job B.
Both Jobs trigger Job C with different parameters.

`build propagate: true, job: 'JobC', parameters: [string(name: 'Test', value: 'false'), string(name: 'Tools', value: 'true')]`

Job C generates artifacts.

How can Job A & Job B pull these artifacts into their workspace?

I did find the plugin copyartifact: https://plugins.jenkins.io/copyartifact/
However, Job A & Job B might trigger Job C at the same time, how can I know which build # Job A triggered and which build # Job B triggered?